# Java regex to extract td content from mavenrepository page

Tags: html, regex, maven, web-scraping

I need to extract license information hyperlinks from maven repository page ( end goal is to find copyright information associated with each maven dependency). Following is the relevant portion of the html.

I want to get all hrefs under the table  which is just below the

### Licenses

tag. In this case it's http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt. There could be other  which has more licenses links and I want to capture them all in list of strings. Kindly help me with the regex to perform that. Alternatively if anybody has other ideas like a rest api to get licenses given artifact identified and version from mavenrepository that will be fantastic. Looking forward to hearing from you. Following is the source page from which I'm trying to scrape the licenses urls. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.5.0

```
<div class="version-section">
                <h2>Licenses</h2>
                <table class="grid" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 16em;">License</th>
                            <th>URL</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt" rel="nofollow">http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an html parser?

Comment: While this problem is limited enough that you probably *could* do it reliably with regexes, I think @horcrux is right that an HTML parser would be a better idea.  Even if you do go the regex route, it's a task most suited for multiple regexes plus some scripting, not just a single regex.  So it would be good to know what language you are using for this task.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I'm using Java

Comment: You know that something like this: http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/usage.html exists? Apart from that also things like this: http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/dependencies.html can be generated via site....Apart from that mvnrepository.com is not a Maven repository...